# Cannot set existing payment profile to be the default for a customer

Tags: ruby, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using the `updateCustomerPaymentProfile` endpoint to try to update a payment profile. This works well, except for the presence of one field: `defaultPaymentProfile`.

There are two different issues.

### 1. Authorize.Net Ruby SDK typing issue

The docs say `defaultPaymentProfile` is an expected field, but the type does not allow it in ruby SDK, see in the official source code:

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-ruby/blob/002019e03a94ef582aa82983edf6a7a1a22b2316/lib/authorize...

I opened [a Github issue](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-ruby/issues/189) about this.

I then monkey patched the type as following:

```rb
module AuthorizeNet::API 
  class CustomerPaymentProfileExType
    xml_accessor :defaultPaymentProfile
  end
end
```

After that, it accepts to send the request but I receive an error response as following:

```
AuthorizeNetException: E00003: The element 'paymentProfile' in namespace 
'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 
'defaultPaymentProfile' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd
```

Which is the second issue...

### 2. Authorize.Net API not accepting the `defaultPaymentProfile` when updating a payment profile

For the record, I dumped the raw XML that is sent to the API once I patched the SDK to be able to actually reach the API:

```xml
<updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>REDACTED</name>
    <transactionKey>REDACTED</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <customerProfileId>REDACTED</customerProfileId>
  <paymentProfile>
    <customerType>individual</customerType>
    <billTo>
      <firstName>REDACTED</firstName>
      <lastName>REDACTED</lastName>
      <address>REDACTED</address>
      <city>REDACTED</city>
      <state>REDACTED</state>
      <zip>REDACTED</zip>
      <country>REDACTED</country>
      <phoneNumber>REDACTED</phoneNumber>
    </billTo>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>XXXX4242</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>2022-03</expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <customerPaymentProfileId>REDACTED</customerPaymentProfileId>
    <!-- This XML passes fine without the line below -->
    <defaultPaymentProfile>true</defaultPaymentProfile>
  </paymentProfile>
  <validationMode>liveMode</validationMode>
</updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest>
```

This looks exactly the same as the request [suggested by the official API docs](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-update-customer-payment-profile), yet, the server respond with a `E00003` error that I already shared above.

### Notes

As a reference, the block of ruby code that I am using:

```rb
        profile = AuthorizeNet::API::CustomerPaymentProfileExType.new
        profile.customerPaymentProfileId = current_profile.customerPaymentProfileId
        profile.billTo = billTo
        profile.payment = AuthorizeNet::API::PaymentType.new(
          AuthorizeNet::API::CreditCardType.new(
            cc_data.cardNumber, cc_data.expirationDate
          )
        ) 
        profile.taxId = user.tax_id if user.tax_id
        profile.defaultPaymentProfile = true
        profile.customerType = 'individual'

        request = AuthorizeNet::API::UpdateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest.new
        request.paymentProfile = profile
        request.customerProfileId = customer_profile_id
        request.validationMode = AuthorizeNet::API::ValidationModeEnum::LiveMode

        response = transaction.update_customer_payment_profile(request)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements matter. Move

```
<defaultPaymentProfile>true</defaultPaymentProfile>`
```

above

```
<customerPaymentProfileId>REDACTED</customerPaymentProfileId>`
```

```
<updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>REDACTED</name>
    <transactionKey>REDACTED</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <customerProfileId>REDACTED</customerProfileId>
  <paymentProfile>
    <customerType>individual</customerType>
    <billTo>
      <firstName>REDACTED</firstName>
      <lastName>REDACTED</lastName>
      <address>REDACTED</address>
      <city>REDACTED</city>
      <state>REDACTED</state>
      <zip>REDACTED</zip>
      <country>REDACTED</country>
      <phoneNumber>REDACTED</phoneNumber>
    </billTo>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>XXXX4242</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>2022-03</expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <defaultPaymentProfile>true</defaultPaymentProfile>
    <customerPaymentProfileId>REDACTED</customerPaymentProfileId>
  </paymentProfile>
  <validationMode>liveMode</validationMode>
</updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest>
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't `defaultPaymentProfile ` already above? Do you mean the contrary? `customerPaymentProfileId` should be above?

Comment: Look at your code. In it `customerPaymentProfileId` occurs before `defaultPaymentProfile`.

Comment: It works by sending the XML in the right order, indeed. Thats terrible, but it works. Thank! :) On the other hand, inverting the assignment statements in the ruby code is useless, because the order depends on the type definition. Monkey patching it was not very easy, so I ended up simply creating a patched type, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John Conde, I could fix the issue. The request payload is refused because the properties are not in the right order.

If you want to set an existing payment profile as the default one using the ruby SDK, you can do so by defining yourself the correct type, as following:

```rb
module AuthorizeNet::API 
  class CustomerPaymentProfileExTypePatched
    include ROXML
    xml_accessor :customerType
    xml_accessor :billTo, as: AuthorizeNet::API::CustomerAddressType
    xml_accessor :payment, as: AuthorizeNet::API::PaymentType
    xml_accessor :driversLicense, as: AuthorizeNet::API::DriversLicenseType
    xml_accessor :taxId
    xml_accessor :defaultPaymentProfile
    xml_accessor :subsequentAuthInformation
    xml_accessor :customerPaymentProfileId

    def initialize(customerType = nil, billTo = nil, payment = nil, driversLicense = nil, taxId = nil, defaultPaymentProfile = nil, subsequentAuthInformation = nil, customerPaymentProfileId = nil)
      @customerType = customerType
      @billTo = billTo
      @payment = payment
      @driversLicense = driversLicense
      @taxId = taxId
      @defaultPaymentProfile = defaultPaymentProfile
      @subsequentAuthInformation = subsequentAuthInformation
      @customerPaymentProfileId = customerPaymentProfileId
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can just use this type in your code:

```rb
profile = AuthorizeNet::API::CustomerPaymentProfileExTypePatched.new
```